# How to send invitation email by desktop version outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, zoom-meeting

After creating a zoom meeting, will send invitation e-mails by outlook.

But from desktop outlook(on macOS), even set from and to and all the necessary informations, can't click the `Send Update` button from menu.

[image]

If do it on web outlook, it can.

[image]

Microsoft Outlook for Mac version: 16.40.

Comment: Does this issue only happen to this specific Outlook for Mac client? It is suggested to try the same operations on other Outlook for Mac clients and see how everything going.

Please check if you can successfully send updates when creating normal Outlook meetings(not zoom meetings) in Outlook for Mac and see if the issue has any difference.

Comment: @JeffYang7 For normal outlook mail, it's possible to click "Send" button.

Comment: Seems that it is more related to the zoom meeting add-in itself, how is everything going now?

Comment: @JeffYang7 Sometimes it works.